# Trouble installing pillow for Windows 10

Tags: python, django, pip, python-imaging-library, easy-install

Having issues installing Pillow for python djgango. I am using Windows 10, Python 3.6.

When I run pip install pillow==3.3.0.

```
ValueError: zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-zlib, aborting
```

My question is how do I properly install its dependency(zlib)?  I cant find any documentation on how to successfully install it in Windows.

Comment: Try the one for 3.4 http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow

Comment: Try downloading the precompiled wheel version [HERE](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)